# Pinch and Zoom imageview

Tags: android, swipe, pinchzoom

I have a task to pinch and zoom the imageview, I have made an app where I am swiping the images and it is working fine; now I want to Pinch and Zoom the imageview on the same class ;but I am not able to do this.I have gone through various example but it seems nothing is helping in this case.Below is my code,or provide me some another example for this problem.

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {        
        @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) { 
 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), image_id[position]);
  bmpWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
  bmpHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
  distCurrent = 1; 
  dist0 = 1;
  drawMatrix();
  float distx, disty;
   switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    //A pressed gesture has started, the motion contains the initial starting location. 
    touchState = TOUCH;
    break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        //A non-primary pointer has gone up. 
        touchState = TOUCH;
        break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
    //A non-primary pointer has gone down. 
    touchState = PINCH;

    //Get the distance when the second pointer touch
    distx = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    disty = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    dist0 = FloatMath.sqrt(distx * distx + disty * disty);

    break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    //A change has happened during a press gesture (between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP).

    if(touchState == PINCH){      
     //Get the current distance
     distx = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
     disty = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
     distCurrent = FloatMath.sqrt(distx * distx + disty * disty);

     drawMatrix();
    }

    break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    //A pressed gesture has finished.
    touchState = IDLE;
    break;
   }
  touchState = IDLE;
            return true;
        }
    });





private void drawMatrix(){
     float curScale = distCurrent/dist0;
     if (curScale < 0.1){
      curScale = 0.1f; 
     }

     Bitmap resizedBitmap;    
     int newHeight = (int) (bmpHeight * curScale);
     int newWidth = (int) (bmpWidth * curScale);
     System.out.println("new width: "+newWidth+" new heigt: "+newHeight);
     resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false);
     System.out.println("resized bitmap: "+resizedBitmap);
     imageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap); 
    }
```

Comment: Try this library https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: Have done this using [a link](http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=c16ed3b4-b422-43ba-b595-ee8e21dd1854).Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

I have to integrate the same functionality into the my application.

But as we know zoomable ImageView is not possible in android.

I have use the following library:
https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom

Try this. May be helps you...:)

Comment: Have done this using [a link](http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=c16ed3b4-b422-43ba-b595-ee8e21dd1854).Thank you all